# Jquery combine click and change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible listen click and change for one code?

```
$(document).on("click", "button.options_buy",function(event) {

//   same code
}


$(document).on("change", "select.options_buy",function(event) {

//   same code
}
```

I try this

```
$(document).on("click change", "button.options_buy,select.options_buy",function(event) { }
```

It works but I want 'click' only for 'button.options_buy' and 'change' for 'select.options_buy'

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do it is to have two event handlers as you have, but only have a common function that is called from each:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.options_buy",function(event) {
  commonFunction();
})


$(document).on("change", "select.options_buy",function(event) {
    commonFunction();
})

function commonFunction(){
//common function code
}
```

Comment: You might as well get rid of the anonymous function and just do `$(document).on("change", "select.options_buy", commonFunction);`

Comment: @Matis Lepik - I was going to, but didn't in case there were other functions in there (that the OP did not include in the post)  that also had to run as well as the common function

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend your code.

```
$(document).on("click change", "button.options_buy,select.options_buy",function(event) {        
  if(event.type=="click"){
        someFunction();
  } else if(event.type=="change"){
        someFunction();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on() to bind a function to multiple events:

```
  $('#foo').on('keypress click change', function(e) {
        //
    });
```

OR declare a function and call it for each event

```
$('#foo')
    .change(myFunction)
    .click(myFunction)
    .blur(myFunction)
```

jQuery [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$( "#foo" ).bind({
  click: function() {
    // Do something on click
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    // Do something on mouseenter
  }
});
```

OR

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "entered" );
});
```